# Composer autoload namespaces

Tags: php, composer, autoload

На работе меня перевели на новый проект, написанный на Yii2. Во многих местах приложение падает из-за того, что не может найти нужный класс. Выяснил, что проблема в том, что вместо того, чтобы написать `\Yii::$app->getRequest()`, предыдущий разработчик упускает обратный слэш в начале вызова, то есть пишет `Yii::$app->getRequest()`, при этом не прописав в начале файла `use Yii;`. Я так понимаю, что раз такая ситуация повторяется почти по всему коду, значит это работало. В чём может быть дело? Возможно дело в том, что мы использовали разные версии PHP?

Answer (score 1):

может у него spl_autoload_register в случае ошибки выполнял use Yii и осуществлялся коннект из корня папки?

Comment: Оказывается, предыдущий разраб просто копипастил код из других мест и забыл написать `use Yii;`.

Comment: Для таких проверок годится любой IDE типа PHPStorm, который пройдется по файлам и скажет что и где не определено.